# How to print a image in console with Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a console application on python, but I need to do like a welcome image, something like this

```
║                                                                          ║
║                    ▄██████▄  ████████▄   ▄█  ███▄▄▄▄                     ║
║                   ███    ███ ███   ▀███ ███  ███▀▀▀██▄                   ║
║                   ███    ███ ███    ███ ███▌ ███   ███                   ║
║                   ███    ███ ███    ███ ███▌ ███   ███                   ║
║      /\           ███    ███ ███    ███ ███▌ ███   ███      /\           ║
║     /  \  /\      ███    ███ ███    ███ ███  ███   ███     /  \  /\      ║
║    /    \/  \     ███    ███ ███   ▄███ ███  ███   ███    /    \/  \     ║
║   /  /\  \   \     ▀██████▀  ████████▀  █▀    ▀█   █▀    /  /\  \   \    ║
║  /__/  \__\   \                                         /__/  \__\   \   ║
║    /  /________\           ▄████████  ▄█   ▄██████▄       /  /________\  ║                         
║   /      \                ███    ███ ███  ███    ███     /      \        ║
║  /________\               ███    ███ ███▌ ███    ███    /________\       ║
║                           ███    ███ ███▌ ███    ███                     ║
║                         ▀███████████ ███▌ ███    ███                     ║
║                           ███    ███ ███  ███    ███                     ║
║                           ███    ███ ███  ███    ███                     ║
║                           ███    █▀  █▀    ▀██████▀                      ║
║                                                                          ║
```

I dont have so much experiencie with this kind of image, It needs to be on the console when the app starts

Thank you so much

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Just stick it in a print statement. You will probably want it to be multi-line. `print("""...""")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get this in text format and print it. You chose if you want it to be in a file like "start_image.txt' and a quick read at the start and printing it.

Let say you saved it this way, at the start of your script you can do :

```
with open("start_image.txt", 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
...
```

Answer (score 2):

@Apo already has a good simple answer on how to store the image, and dump it to the screen.

However, if you want better terminal handling, you may wish to investigate using something like the [Python "curses" library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html).

This library allows you to interact with the console window with a much finer level of control, allowing things like:

- Clearing the console window
- Querying the size and capabilities of the console
- Writing text in colour
- Writing text at specific locations
- ... and much more

One hint: curses has a habit of messing-up your console settings if the code doesn't exist cleanly, especially if you turn-off key-press echos, etc. in your program.  The (unix) command `reset` usually fixes all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal is not an image displayer thus you need to have the workaround , you may use `bitmap` or as @Apo mentioned use a `.txt` file
Create your file manually and print the file to the terminal
**SUGGESTION :** You may use `ASCII` to make a depth to your image [ASCII Emoji](https://upli.st/l/list-of-all-ascii-emoticons) and [Convert Text to ASCII](https://fsymbols.com/generators/carty/) , then put it into your file

Answer (score 1):

there are several ascii art libraries for python.

for example this one: https://pypi.org/project/art/